# save & reload directionService.route response

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I have an application that takes an address as input from user. For the given input, I find out a list of addresses (saved in database) in < 2 KMS distance. I have lat&long information of the address in database. Each address has a from&to points. Lat&Long for these from & to points are also in database.

Now I need to draw lines between these from&to points in google maps. I use Javascript to do this. For any given address, I will have atleast 50 lines to be drawn. Due to OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, I wanted to save this response in database as string and then convert it back into object and display in google maps.

Please note that I always have only a list of known address. These addresses are saved in database with From&To lat&long. So I could also write a cronjob which would retrieve response for given fromlat&long & to-lat&long like this.

```
var directionsDisplay<?php print $i; ?> = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);  
directionsDisplay<?php print $i; ?>.setMap(map); 
var start<?php print $i; ?> = '<?php echo $address1; ?>'; 
var end<?php print $i; ?> = '<?php echo $address2; ?>'; 
var request<?php print $i; ?> = { 
    origin:start<?php print $i; ?>,  
    destination:end<?php print $i; ?>, 

    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING 

}; 

<?php if(isempty($routestr)) { ?> 
directionsService.route(request<?php print $i; ?>, function(response, status) { 
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { 
        var routestr = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4); 
        //Saving routestr in database using ajax call
        directionsDisplay<?php print $i; ?>.setDirections(response);
    }
}
<?php } //end of $routestr check 
else { //convert $routestr into response and assign to setDirections method
  ?>
  //PHP $routestr is a JSON object automatically. so eval function will not work.
  //var response1 = eval('(' + <?php print $routestr; ?> + ')');

  var response1 = <?php echo $routestr; ?>; //This works.
  alert(response1.status); //displays OK. So I am assured that this is a JSON object now.
   directionsDisplay<?php print $i; ?>.setDirections(response1); //This still does not work. Map is blank

<?php    }//end of $routestr else check ?>
```

I am facing issue in else part. eval method does not convert the object correctly. Therefore when I call setDirections(response1) does not work.

Can someone pls help? I want to convert my JSON string back to DirectionsResult object

I also checked https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult. Here is a line "Note that though this result is "JSON-like," it is not strictly JSON, as it indirectly includes LatLng objects."

I tested this code in a html file

```
var res = new google.maps.DirectionsResult(); //I receive js error This is not a class and cannot be instantiated. Don't understand how they send back this as response in route method call.
res1.status = "OK"; //Becoz of above issue, this will not work
alert(res1.status); //Becoz of above issue, this will not work
```

But this alert message is never executed. Nothing is displayed. Don't know why.

Guys don't try this. This will not work out.

Currently, I have changed my code & implemented timeout. I read somewhere that we can make upto 5 request every second to directionsService. OVER_QUERY_LIMIT will be returned, if we exceed 5 requests within a second.

Implementing timeout has slowed down the final response. But there seems to be no other way. Not sure if getting this service as business api would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having that problem too. But in my case, I need to draw that route back and allow the user to drag the route (same property that exists when we made a route request) and update the lat lng in BD. If you only need to draw the line between these two points that you already have, you could just request a new route. If you have Over_query_limit problem you can save the LatLng that is in response.routes[0].overview_path and draw it back with a simple Polyline parsing LatLng as Path. Of course this won't be precisely as a new route request.

Comment: I tried this:

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var str = JSON.stringify(response);
 var obj = JSON.parse(str);
 directionsDisplay.setDirections(str);
      }
    });

and browser returned Error in property <routes>:(the value it's not an Array). Line 1 main.js.
So I believe that the object became corrupted in JSON.parse(str).
I don't even know if it's allowed to save Google Data.

Comment: I already tried drawing polyline. but this is not the right solution, becoz sometimes the street is L shaped with continuing nos. Drawing a polyline would be just a overlaying line and would not be synchronized with the street line on map.

Comment: I already tried this. you should try it as directionsDisplay.setDirections(obj); But this will not work since DirectionsResult (obj) is a JSON-like object only and not fully JSON. So stringfying and parsing back does not really help.

Comment: When you drag a line that is made of a request, something is changed. If you print the length of Response.routes[0].legs[i].steps[i] you will realize that the object change without a request to Google servers. What you can do is save the infos that exists in steps and legs and also save the reference of objects. In other words you will simulate a draggin, but parsin the info you already have.